# File path (JAVA EE)

Tags: java, file, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I'm working in a web project and I'm having troubles with files(`java.io.File`). The problem is only when I run as web application(**tomcat 7**), if I run as Java Application, the problem doesn't exist.

When I instantiate a file, `new File("dir");`, its path become C://Windows/System32/dir, this way, i can't do anything, maybe cause don't have Windows privilegies.

"I solved the problem" passing `new File("C://Users/user/dir")`, but I don't like this solution. I wanted to do this automatically, get the app path, for example. I'm coding in my machine, and after the deploy.... i don't know.

Any tips?

That's the part of the project that I'm having the problem, a jsf bean. My view calls the method `addFile()` to save the file that I receive from my view. It's working, but i have to pass the path like I said before, like is on the code below. The path goes to the Windows dir System32

```
Bean.java

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    //ATTRIBUTES AND METHODS

    public void addFile() {

        File temporaryFile = new File("temporary");
        //...
        //...
        //...

    }
}
```

Sorry for my english, i'm brazillian.

Comment: Use `createTempFile()`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in the File class that does exactly what you're looking for: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Alternatively you can assemble the file's path yourself:

```
File myTempFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),"temporary");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add folder resources in web folder then add files as you want 
i tested it from adding some styles (css) and javascript and call them in jsf page.as example if you create file named x in folder files under web/resources folder

```
new File("files/x");
```

wishing the answer helps you .you can tell me if any problem happens again

Comment: i created the folder "files" in web/resources and continues with the same problem.

Comment: `System.out.println(new File("temp").getAbsolutePath());` OUT: "C:\Windows\System32\files\x"

Comment: no , i meant that you should create folder called resources in folder web that existed in your project and this is your home

Comment: i did exatcly this, actually, this folder already exists, exatcly for css, js....

Comment: Björn Zurmaar, asked too and his solution worked. but, thanks for the help.